# converting Matlab to python code : IndexError: index -1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Tags: python, matlab

Converting Matlab code to python . IndexError: index -1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
Matlab
++++++

```
for i = 1:N
            for j=1:N
                s = zeros(L2,L2);
                sX = zeros(L2,L2);
                sSS= Y((i-1)*L2+1:i*L2,(j-1)*L2+1:j*L2);
                BI{i,j} = sSS;
```

Python
++++++

```
for i in range(N):
        for j in range(N):
            s = zeros(N, N);
            sX = zeros(N,N);
            sSS =Y[arange(dot((i - 1),L2) + 1,dot(i,L2)),arange(dot((j - 1),L2) + 1,dot(j,L2))]
            BI [i,j] = sSS
```

IndexError: index -1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0.  According to the line of BI [i,j] = sSS.
The index difference between matlab and python. Matlab starts index 1 and Python starts index 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATLAB indices `(i-1)*L2+1:i*L2,(j-1)*L2+1:j*L2` are simply translated into Python's as this `i*L2:(i+1)*L2, j*L2:(j+1)*L2`. You should initialize `BI` outside the loops and `s`, `sX` does nothing inside the loops. Also, `Y` is not defined outside the loops.

Note, you shouldn't import everything from numpy like this, it should be `import numpy as np` and use `np.func(..)` wherever you want. `BI` was defined as a list which is closer to a *cell array* in MATLAB.

```
from numpy import *    # not recommended to import everything

N = L2 = 5
Y = random.rand(100,100)
BI = []
for i in range(N):
    BI.append([])
    for j in range(N):
        # s = zeros((L2,L2))  # does nothing
        # sX = zeros((L2,L2)) # does nothing
        sSS = Y[i*L2:(i+1)*L2, j*L2:(j+1)*L2]
        BI[i].append(sSS)
```